# How do I get Unifying Keyboard to swap caps lock and control key on Mac OS-X?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I recently bought the Logitech K320 keyboard.  However, when I tried to swap my caps lock key and control key via system preferences, it wouldn't take.  Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me, but I'm using an Apple keyboard. You could try [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html). Besides that and *Modifier Keys...*, there aren't many other easy ways to remap ⇪.